# How to view binary data in tv?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, television

I have some data stored as binaries in mnesia, how can I view the data (e.g. as <<"data_content">>) in tv? It seems that tv only shows binary data as <<#BIN>>.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [14B03 Release Notes](http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R14B03.readme), this has been fixed for binaries =< 100 bytes in ets and mnesia tables.